# Sending data from unity to firebase producing error - Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Just use Unity3d with Firebase I have a url of database where i want to send data.
 Code below i am using

```
 void Start()
    {
        BtnSendScore();
    }

    public void BtnSendScore() {
        StartCoroutine(SendScore("Muhammad Faizan Khan", 100));
    }

    public IEnumerator SendScore(string name, int score){

        string url = "https://xyz.firebaseio.com/scores.json";
        WWWForm objForm =new  WWWForm();
        objForm.AddField("playerName", name);
        objForm.AddField("score", score);
        objForm.AddField("scoreDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        WWW www = new WWW(url, objForm);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Adedd ::" + www.data);
        }
        else {
            Debug.LogError("Error ::" + www.error);
        }
    }
```

Found this error? What the problem is i check on stackoverflow with jquery it talking about stringify.

> Adedd ::{   "error" : "Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object,
>   array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key
>   names." }

Remember I didn't mess with database in firebase just create database and got url. No keys added.

Answer (score 2):

To write to the Firebase Database using the REST API, you'll need to pass the data as JSON in the body of the request. The Firebase REST API does not take the data as form parameters. See the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) for some examples of how the API works.

[This post](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/www-wwwform-to-post-json-data-to-server-solved.57490/) looks like a promising starting point as does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312091/unity3d-www-post-data-async).

Comment: somehow managed to run the above code sample with some modiification but now getting "Permission denied" error. although auth anonymous enabled

Comment: I have change rules tab setting into database now it  works. thanks

Comment: but my data is not showing in db why? while i got response from server is {"name":"-KPq-LPtHz4Tl9la0Qor"} what is this

Comment: could it be encrypted or something?  try writing a few more.

Comment: @JoeBlow no data found in database